# HTML & CSS without JS. inline-block, :hover, border

Tags: html, css

Good day! I apologize for my English.
the question is:
by task, a block is created in the center of the page with the elements.

1picture

[image]

all lements have a box-sizing: border-box;
 at the cursor position above the elements - all elements get transparency, except for one cursor over it. this position is done.

2picture

[image]

At the beginning of the frame, the elements are specified in part:

```css
 .content>div:not(:last-child) {
 border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;/*всем элементам кроме последнего нижняя рамка*/
}

.content>div:nth-child(2n):not(:nth-child(10)) {
 border-right: 5px solid #fff;/*всем чётным кроме последнего рамка справа*/
}

.content>div:nth-child(2n-1):not(:nth-child(4n-1)) {
 border-right: 5px solid #fff;/* выборка оставшихся элементов рамка справа*/
}
```

to avoid doubling the borderers. by task - a single boarder is displayed.

this is the form

3picture

[image]

Further. when you move the cursor over an element, the element gets opacity: 1; and the mapping of all four Borders.

since the borderers are partially installed, with .element: Hover {} add the missing border. Border - the top is installed without problems, to display a single board - set the margin - top: -5 pixels, while the element is stretched vetically without pulling the bottom element behind it. if you set a horizontal border, left or right,then the element is compressed and two boundaries are displayed, the neighboring element and the neighboring one. when you move 5 pixels to the left, the element does not stretch, and the moving element pulls after it.

picture4

[image]

The question: what parameters to set to an element that would show a single frame with four sides when hovering, and the element did not move.

All the code: https://github.com/evgenjnr/weather-forecast-test.git
Page of result task: https://evgenjnr.github.io/weather-forecast-test/

Using only HTML & CSS, inline-block, without float, flex-box.

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier, if you just had a 5px border on all sides on all elements, and used negative margins to get them to overlap ...

Comment: if install boarders on all sides and using negativ margin i had trident on right saide of elements. Because different namber of elements in rows

Comment: Then reset `box-sizing` to `content-box` for those elements.

Comment: Can you create a snippet in the question of what you have now? A github repository is not easy to work with.

Comment: this is my first post. i can`t edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of borders you can use `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px white;` that way you don't have to handle each case individually.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeeWqr

Answer (score 0):

decided to install elements of the content box on all sides of the border at once, setting the width through calc (width - 5px) and margin - left -5px

now copy to GitHub

Comment: visual: https://evgenjnr.github.io/weather-forecast-test/

code:https://github.com/evgenjnr/weather-forecast-test.git

Comment: and - special thanks to - @ApusApus for alternative code